# ArcGis javascript api 3.5 how to set visibility of a feature layer

Tags: arcgis

i am using ArcGis javascript api 3.5 and my code is

```
 map = new esri.Map("mapDiv", {
            basemap: "streets",
            center: [-112.07102547942392, 46.75909704205151],
            zoom: 12,
            slider: false,
            infoWindow: infoWindow
        });




        var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http:/abc/arcgis/rest/services/MTARNG/MapServer/1", {
            mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
            infoTemplate: templateFuze,
            outFields: ["*"]
        });
        var featureLayer1 = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://abc/arcgis/rest/services/MTARNG/MapServer/0", {
            mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
            infoTemplate: templateParcel,
            outFields: ["*"]
        });
        var featureLayer2 = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://abc/arcgis/rest/services/MTARNG/MapServer/2", {
            mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
            infoTemplate: templateGrid,
            outFields: ["*"]
        });

            Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                width: 400,
                height: 600,
                bodyPadding: 10,
                renderTo: Ext.get('LayerDiv'),
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                    columns: 1,
                    vertical: true,
                    items: layerInfo,
                    listeners: {

                        change: {
                            fn: function (checkbox, checked) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.items.items.length; i++) {
                                    if (checkbox.items.items[i].checked) {
                                        //visible true checkbox.items.items[0].boxLabel                                        

                                    }
                                    else {
                                        //visible false 
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            });

        });
```

So i am trying to set the visibilty of the layer but i am not able to do. after that how to refresh the map ?

I got some function but it is working e.g.-  visibleAtMapScale = false,
defaultVisibility = false and for refreshing i got only map.resize=true;

What else i can try to achive this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enable intellisense support in Visual Studio you can download and reference the code assist plugin from the Esri website. There is a help page about it [here](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/api_codeassist.html) with links to the various versions supported and how to use it from VS.

If you just want to get the VS2012 version for v3.5 of the JS API it is [here](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/jsapi_vsdoc12_v35.zip) and to reference it:

If working in an HTML file, add a script tag to add a reference to the code assist

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='path_to_vsdoc.js'></script>
```

If working in a JavaScript file, add a reference directive to the VSDoc file:

```
  /// <reference path="~/Scripts/esri-jsapi-vsdoc.js" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You can change the visibility of an layer using the hide() and show() functions - FeatureLayer inherits them from GraphicsLayuer (Which inherits them from Layer).  So in your example, given featureLayer is a global variable it should be in scope when the event fires so you could just do:

`featureLayer.hide();`

and

`featureLayer.show();`

You don't need to refresh the map, it will happen automatically.

Simon

Comment: Thank you Simon it is working. but why these functions are not visible in Quick Watch(i am using Visual studio 2012) and from where you know these function (Any reference) ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said.  Have a look here: http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/ there are lots of useful samples for when getting started but also have a look at the API Reference (linked at the top) which describes the properties, methods and events of each object.  I'm not sure why Quick Watch didn't report it, perhaps Quick Watch isn't clever enough to determine methods / properties that are inherited from base class.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html), you can specify the default visibility using the [optional parameters](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#featurelayer1). The default is true.

```
var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http:/.../MapServer/1",     
      {visible:false}
});
```

To set the visibility of the existing layer, you can use the [setVisibility()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#setvisibility) method.

```
featureLayer.setVisibility(false);
```